# как прибить блок к низу если есть скролл(landscape)

Tags: html, css, прокрутка, height

[image],[image],[image],[image],[image]
Всем привет,в общем у меня такая проблема,делаю мобайл меню и в режиме ландскейпа у меня появляться скролл и социал меню,у которого боттом 0,берет низ от высоты экрана мобайл меню которое установленно 100vh,как мне сделать так чтобы оно было в самом низу?(за экраном),простите если я непонятно выражаюсь,очень мало опыта,скрины приложил!

Comment: Код вставьте либо в сниппете, либо используя \```<!-- какой-то код -->```. (Код вставлять в вопросе, а не в комментариях)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) and (max-height:460px) { 
  .mob-menu{
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

Что-то по типу этого

Comment: к сожалению не решает мою проблему

Comment: переделайте картинки в редактор кода... так сложно ориентироваться. Как была получена первая картинка непонятно по CSS... там элемент Game он же элемент одного меню, а по факту идет после меню с социалками...